# Adding and using 'PHP' External Libraries into JetBrains PhpStorm?

Tags: php, libraries, phpstorm

I'm having this problematic issue:

[image]

Anyone have an idea of whats going on, I have added the path to the folder in the 'Include Path' configuration in 'Settings' and still it's giving me that.

Comment: Have you tried including the library root name in the `include` statement?

Comment: @DavidPostill yup -> http://i.imgur.com/EMFpf8t.png